# Python : Finding commonalities in multiple array of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, find

I have an array of dicts. I don't know how many dicts will be inside of this list because the result is different by data. 
I have to find commonalities by values from those. Once I find common things, then I have to merge those dicts that have same values and figure out the frequency of this values.

This is sample data.

```
[
 { 
   "id": 100
   "category": null,
   "mid": null
 },
 {
   "id": 100
   "city": "roma"
  },
  { 
   "id": 100
   "category": null,
   "mid": null
 },
 {
   "id": 100
   "city": "roma"
  },
 {
   "id": 200
   "category": "red",
   "mid": null
  },
  {
   "id": 200
   "region": "toscany"
  },
 {
   "id": 300
   "category": "blue",
   "mid": "cold",
   "sub": null
  },
 {
   "id": 400
   "category": "yellow",
   "mid": "warm"
  },
 {
   "id": 400
   "city": "milano"
  }
 ]
```

and the expected result should be like this.

```
[
 { 
   "id": 100
   "category": null,
   "mid": null,
   "city": "roma"
   "count": 2
 },
 {
   "id": 200
   "category": "red",
   "mid": null,
   "region": "toscany",
   "count": 1
  },
 {
   "id": 300
   "category": "blue",
   "mid": "cold",
   "sub": null,
   "count": 1
  },
 {
   "id": 400
   "category": "yellow",
   "mid": "warm",
   "city": "milano",
   "count": 1
  }
 ]
```

I know how to find commonalities from two dicts but have no idea with multiple dicts. Maybe I can use items() to find same values and chainmap() to merge but till now kept failed to expected result.

Edit 
What I did when I have only two dicts.

```
a={ 
   "id": 100,
   "category": null,
   "mid": null
 }
 b={
   "id": 100,
   "city": "roma"
  }
def grouping_records():
    rows.sort(key=itemgetter('id'))
    for date, items in groupby(rows, key=itemgetter('id')):
        print(id)
        for i in items:
                print(' ', i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    grouping_records()
```

Comment: "I know how to find commonalities from two dicts" -- can you show how you would do this, so we can help you think about generalizing your logic?

Comment: What exactly does the frequency refer to? Which values require counting?

Comment: Can you break down why id 100 count is 2? Is it count different dictionaries with same id? Or could it be you count the max or min number of repetitions of each dictionary, it is not true? Below I suggested solution should at least merge dictionaries (unless you absolutely need use groupby)

Comment: As for 200 count is 2 I lean to theory that you need the max or min number of repetitions of dictionary per id.

Answer (score 1):

groupby is a bit complex for many of us, try this naive solution

```
mylist = [dict(s) for s in set(frozenset(d.items()) for d in original)] # remove dublicate dictionaries if needed
ids = set([d['id'] for d in mylist])
id_cnt = {id: {"count": ids.count(id)} for id in ids }
for d in mylist:
     id = d['id']
     id_cnt[id].update(d)
result = id_cnt.values()
```